# Using groupby function in Hive to get category counts, but one category is missing in output table as data is not available in input table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Hive script issue: I have an issue with getting counts over groupby using Hive, when the count is zero. If a category is available in input table, I was able to see the counts in output table. But when a particular category is not available in input table, it doesnt appear as zero in output table. Instead that category is vanished from output table. Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Input and Output Tables:**
[image]

Input table is partitioned on "Year" column.

**Hive Code I tried:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your query.. this may not be the most optimized approach but this is what i can think of

1. You have got the code output table as a result in your query
2. You can use left join with code_output_table on year and ada

https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/How-to-return-a-zero-in-SQL-instead-of-no-row-back-for-a-select-count